# rearranging string containing repeating patterns of variable length

Tags: parsing, list, haskell

I have a file with the following layout:

> TABLE name_of_table
>
> COLUMNS first_column 2nd_column [..] n-th_column
>
> VALUES 1st_value 2nd_value [...] n-th value
>
> VALUES yet_another_value ... go on
>
> ANOTHER TABLE repeat from begin.....

I want to have this textfile rearranged for me, so I don't have to type in the TABLE and COLUMNS in front of every VALUES line, yielding:

> TABLE name_of_table COLUMNS first_column [..] n-th column VALUES **1st_value**
>
> TABLE name_of_table COLUMNS first_column [..] n-th column VALUES **yetanother_value**

I need to take input and rearrange several lines at once here, so getting the entire textfile as a string with **hGetContents** seems appropriate, yielding a string like this:

> TABLE name_of_table COLUMNS first_column [..] n-th_column VALUES 1st_value [..] n-th_value VALUES another_value [..] yet_another VALUES ...... ANOTHER TABLE .... COLUMNS .... VALUES [....]VALUES ...

I have tried doing this with nested case of's and recursion. This gives me a dilemma I need help with:

1) I need recursion in order to avoid endless case nesting problems.

2) with recursion, I can't have as an alternative adding the previous parts of the string, as the recursion only references the tail of my string!

Illustrating the problem:

`myStr::[[Char]]->[[Char]]
myStr []   = []
myStr one  =
 case (head one) of
  "table" -> "insert into":(head two):columnRecursion (three) ++ case (head four) of 
                                                                  "values" -> (head four):valueRecursion (tail three) ++ myStr (tail four)
                                                                  _        -> case head (tail four) of
                                                                               "values" -> (head (tail four):myStr (tail (tail four))
                                                                               _        -> 
 where two   = tail one
       three = tail two
       four  = tail three

columnRecursion::[[Char]] -> [[Char]]
columnRecursion [] = []
columnRecursion cool =
 case (head cool) of
  "columns"         -> "(":columnRecursion (tail cool) 
  "values"          -> [")"]
  _                 -> (head cool):columnRecursion (tail cool)

valueRecursion::[[Char]] -> [[Char]]
valueRecursion foo =
 case head foo of
  "values" -> "insert into":(head two):columnRecursion (three) ++ valueRecursion (tail foo)
  "table"  -> []
  "columns"-> []
  _        -> (head foo):valueRecursion (tail foo)`

I wind up with FIRSTPART, VALUES bla bla VALUES bla bla, and I can't fetch FIRSTPART again, to create FIRSTPART, VALUES, FIRSTPART, VALUES, FIRSTPART, VALUES.

The attempt to do this by referencing myStr in valueRecursion is obviously out of scope.

What to do??

Comment: Seems like you need to take a two pronged approach -- parse the input into a sane data structure, then walk the data structure to produce the munged output.  I'll take a look and see if I find an elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

For me this kind of problem would be just past the use-a-real-parsing-tool threshold. Here's a quick working example with [Attoparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec):

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Attoparsec (maybeResult)
import Data.Attoparsec.Char8
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.Char8 as A (takeWhile)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

data Entry = Entry String [String] [[String]] deriving (Show)

entry = Entry <$> table <*> cols <*> many1 vals
items = sepBy1 (A.takeWhile $ notInClass " \n") $ char ' '
table = string (B.pack "TABLE ") *> many1 (notChar '\n') <* endOfLine
cols = string (B.pack "COLUMNS ") *> (map B.unpack <$> items) <* endOfLine
vals = string (B.pack "VALUES ")  *> (map B.unpack <$> items) <* endOfLine

parseEntries :: B.ByteString -> Maybe [Entry]
parseEntries = maybeResult . flip feed B.empty . parse (sepBy1 entry skipSpace)
```

And a bit of machinery:

```
pretty :: Entry -> String
pretty (Entry t cs vs)
  = unwords $ ["TABLE", t, "COLUMNS"]
  ++ cs ++ concatMap ("VALUES" :) vs

layout :: B.ByteString -> Maybe String
layout = (unlines . map pretty <$>) . parseEntries

testLayout :: FilePath -> IO ()
testLayout f = putStr . fromMaybe [] =<< layout <$> B.readFile f
```

And given this input:

```
TABLE test
COLUMNS a b c
VALUES 1 2 3
VALUES 4 5 6

TABLE another
COLUMNS x y z q
VALUES 7 8 9 10
VALUES 1 2 3 4
```

We get the following:

```
*Main> testLayout "test.dat" 
TABLE test COLUMNS a b c VALUES 1 2 3 VALUES 4 5 6
TABLE another COLUMNS x y z q VALUES 7 8 9 10 VALUES 1 2 3 4
```

Which seems to be what you want?

Comment: Which is exactly what I want! =) I was hoping to create this parser myself, but I realize it might take some more work than fiddling around with my elementary level. ^^

Answer (score 0):

This answer is [literate Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Literate_programming), so you can copy-and-paste it into a file named `table.lhs` to get a working program.

Beginning with a few imports

```
> import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
> import Control.Monad (forM_)
> import Data.List (intercalate,isPrefixOf)
> import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
```

and say we represent a table with the following record:

```
> data Table = Table { tblName :: String
>                    , tblCols :: [String]
>                    , tblVals :: [String]
>                    }
>   deriving (Show)
```

That is, we record the table's name, the list of column names, and the list of column values.

Each table in the input starts on a line beginning with `TABLE`, so separate all lines in the input into chunks accordingly:

```
> tables :: [String] -> [Table]
> tables [] = []
> tables xs = next : tables ys
>   where next = mkTable (th:tt)
>         (th:rest) = dropWhile (not . isTable) xs
>         (tt,ys) = break isTable rest
>         isTable = ("TABLE" `isPrefixOf`)
```

Having chunked the input into tables, the name of a given table is the first word on the `TABLE` line. The column names are all words that appear on `COLUMNS` lines, and column values come from `VALUES` lines:

```
> mkTable :: [String] -> Table
> mkTable xs = Table name cols vals
>   where name = head $ fromJust $ lookup "TABLE" tagged
>         cols = grab "COLUMNS"
>         vals = grab "VALUES"
>         grab t = concatMap snd $ filter ((== t) . fst) tagged
>         tagged = map ((head &&& tail) . words)
>                $ filter (not . null) xs
```

Given a `Table` record, we print it by pasting the names, values, and SQL keywords together in the appropriate order on a single line:

```
> main :: IO ()
> main = do
>   input <- readFile "input"
>   forM_ (tables $ lines input) $
>     \t -> do putStrLn $ intercalate " " $
>                 "TABLE"   : (tblName t)  :
>                ("COLUMNS" : (tblCols t)) ++
>                ("VALUES"  : (tblVals t))
```

Given the unimaginative input of

```
TABLE name_of_table

COLUMNS first_column 2nd_column [..] n-th_column

VALUES 1st_value 2nd_value [...] n-th value

VALUES yet_another_value ... go on

TABLE name_of_table

COLUMNS first_column 2nd_column [..] n-th_column

VALUES 1st_value 2nd_value [...] n-th value

VALUES yet_another_value ... go on
```

the output is

```
$ runhaskell table.lhs
TABLE name_of_table COLUMNS first_column 2nd_column [..] n-th_column VALUES 1st_value 2nd_value [...] n-th value yet_another_value ... go on
TABLE name_of_table COLUMNS first_column 2nd_column [..] n-th_column VALUES 1st_value 2nd_value [...] n-th value yet_another_value ... go on
```